# panel visibility does not working inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, panel, visibility

I have an update panel which contains a label and a panel, with "visible=false" for both of them..when user clicked the report button a please wait pop up appears and after that results are shown, it works fine but when i published it the panel visibility does not working and nothing happens!!!!! here is my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<ContentTemplate>
    <p><asp:Label ID="Label_err" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"  Visible ="False"></asp:Label></p>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel_ReportResults" runat="server"  Direction="RightToLeft" Font-Names="Tahoma" Visible="False">
    <!--a table which contains a link and a link button is here-->
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

and at the server side there is some code like this to handle the visibility:

```
if (!Error)
           {
               log.SaveReporting();
               Panel_ReportResults.Visible = true;
               Label_err.Visible = false;
           }
           else
           {
               Panel_ReportResults.Visible = false;
               Label_err.Visible = true;
           }
```

everything works fine for the label..and also it works fine before publishing it! please help! thanks.

Comment: You have javascript errors, open the console to locate them and show them here.

Comment: Yes...that was the problem...Thanks a lot :)